# MPMoviePlayerViewController repeatMode not working?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a problem with  MPMoviePlayerViewController and it's property repeatMode. It's stated that setting it to a MPMovieRepeatModeOne value will cause player to repeat playback. I use following code to play video in a loop but it just stops after the end.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
mpViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL= movieURL;
self.aPlayer=mpViewController;
self.aPlayer.moviePlayer.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mpViewController.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

worked for me but I did not have the url line or the self.'s

My next line after the above was `[mpViewController play];`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line

[self.aPlayer.moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];

and put:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidChangeState:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.player];
```

and implement

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidChangeState:(NSNotification *)note
{


    MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = [self.player playbackState];
    if(playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped ||playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused || playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
    {
        if (note.object == self.player) {
            NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
            if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
            {
                [self.player play];
            }
        }
    }
}
```